# Matlab cpselect with RGB fixed image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-registration

I would like to be able to use the cpselect matlab tool (or a similar one) with the capability of showing both images (moving image and reference image) in RGB (I only managed to see moving image in RGB and reference image in grayscale).

Could someone point me to an alternative for this tool that would support this or anyway to be able to display both image in rgb in cpselect?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're talking about, and I'm quite confused about your statement.  `cpselect` is image independent.  You can show both of them as colour or grayscale or one or the other.  The example you're probably looking at is the one that comes with MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/cpselect.html .  One image is grayscale, while the other has a pinkish hue.

Here's an example showing both the source and target image as being in colour.  I used `onion.png` that is a colour image that is part of the MATLAB system path:

```
im = imread('onion.png');
im_rotate = imrotate(im, 35);
cpselect(im, im_rotate);
```

We get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after it I realised that my problem was that I was using an indexed fixed image that first needed to be converted to an rgb image to be displayed in color in the control point selection tool.